# Get Bitcoin value from Binance by HTMLagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I try to get the bitcoin value shown on Binance (**https://www.binance.com/en**) by using the HTML agility pack and copying the xpath given by inspector:

```
public async void checkbi()
    {
        var url = "https://www.binance.com";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode plek = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[4]/div/div/a[2]/div[2])");

        waarde = plek.InnerText;

        label1.Text = waarde.ToString();
    }
```

However, although everything seems to work fine, I don't get the value, but just -.

Anybody knows what's going wrong?

Comment: How did you get that node path? I'm willing to bet they use some front-end-js-framework. Your node path will not work in that case, you'd have to get your path from the raw html source, NOT the browser console inspector tool.

Comment: Confirmed, they are using React. Good luck finding the xpath.

Comment: Thanks. Found out I can view the raw HTML code by right click 'view source', however the bitcoin is unfindable here. Any ideas on how to achieve what I want with the HTML agility pack?

Comment: You will not be able to use the agility pack in that case, they are retrieving the data via a server request. Unless you can intercept it and make the call yourself, your going to be fighting a battle here.  Don't they have an API or something you can call instead?